# how I can save the data in array based on the added row table with using method post?

Tags: javascript, php

how i can post data if i using add row table with function click add ??
this my code :

```
<form id="login" action = "product2.php" method = "POST" name="product-form">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Max Item
        </td>
        <td>
            :
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="max" id="maxitem">
                <?php
                for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++)
                {
                    echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Product
        </td>
        <td>
        :
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="product" id="product" value="" placeholder="Add Product" size="40">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="ADD" value="Add Item">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </br>
    <table border="1" id="tblname" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Total Item
            </td>
            <td>
                Name Item
            </td>
            <td>
                DELETE
            </td>
        <tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody align="center">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
```

and this is javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var item = 1;
$('#ADD').click(function(){
    var maxitem = parseInt($("#maxitem").val(), 10); //from max item in html
    var iCount = 0;
    if($('#product').val()){  // check input product
        if( item <= maxitem )
        {
            iCount = $('#tblname tbody tr').length + 1;
            szTr = "<tr><td>";
            szTr = szTr + iCount + "</td>";
            szTr = szTr +   "<td>" +$('#product').val() +"</td>";
            szTr = szTr +   "<td><input type='button' class='DEL' value='DELETE'></td>";
            szTr = szTr +   "</tr>";                     
            $('#tblname tbody').append(szTr);
            item +=1;
        }
        else
        {
            alert ("Max Limit !!!");
        }
    }else{alert('Enter Text');}
});

// for delete row
$('body').on('click', 'input.DEL', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();  
    item -= 1;
});
});
```

this code html and js already work well, but i don't know how i can post data product ???

and this my code in product2.php

```
<?php
$maxitem = $_POST['max'];
$products = array();
$products [] = $_POST['product']; // ??? how i can keep each value product with array ??
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this you need to make change in your javascript code and define product name as array....I think this may help you out.

```
<form id="login" action = "" method = "POST" name="product-form">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Max Item
        </td>
        <td>
            :
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="max" id="maxitem">
                <?php
                for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++)
                {
                    echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Product
        </td>
        <td>
        :
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="product[]" id="product" value="" placeholder="Add Product" size="40">

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="ADD" value="Add Item">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </br>
    <table border="1" id="tblname" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Total Item
            </td>
            <td>
                Name Item
            </td>
            <td>
                DELETE
            </td>
        <tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody align="center">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>  

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
var item = 1;
$('#ADD').click(function(){
    var maxitem = parseInt($("#maxitem").val(), 10); //from max item in html
    var iCount = 0;
    if($('#product').val()){  // check input product
        if( item <= maxitem )
        {
            iCount = $('#tblname tbody tr').length + 1;
            szTr = "<tr><td>";
            szTr = szTr + iCount + "</td>";
            szTr = szTr +   "<td><input type='hidden' name='product[]' value='"+$('#product').val()+"' />" +$('#product').val() +"</td>";
            szTr = szTr +   "<td><input type='button' class='DEL' value='DELETE'></td>";
            szTr = szTr +   "</tr>";                     
            $('#tblname tbody').append(szTr);
            item +=1;
        }
        else
        {
            alert ("Max Limit !!!");
        }
    }else{alert('Enter Text');}
});

// for delete row
$('body').on('click', 'input.DEL', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();  
    item -= 1;
});
});
    </script>
```

Comment: that work well , but when i try in post ($products = $_POST['product']; (e.g i input 1,2,3)
 foreach($products as $p)
 {
  echo $p;
 }
 and result is 3123, it's should be 123 ???

Comment: Please remove name= product from first text box <input type="text" name="product[]" id="product" value="" placeholder="Add Product" size="40"> this will work fine

Answer (score 0):

put your input element product name in array

```
    <input type="text" name="product[]" id="product" value="" placeholder="Add Product" size="40">
```

also do the same with javascript then you will receive array in php

Comment: I follow your instruction but my add row table does not work, i change name and id from "product " to array product[], sorry i am not good in javascript.

Comment: @Vilthering What did you get?? Did you added jquery file to your code? Write down following line before your script tag. 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: that will work, and do you want to create multiple input element on add row click, like as a user click add button, a input element with delete button should created ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, replace yours using this.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);exit;
}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="login" action = "stack2.php" method = "POST" name="product-form">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Max Item
            </td>
            <td>
                :
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="max" id="maxitem">
                    <?php
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
                        echo "<option value=" . $i . ">" . $i . "</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Product
            </td>
            <td>
                :
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="product[]" id="product" value="" placeholder="Add Product" size="40">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="ADD" value="Add Item">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </br>
    <table border="1" id="tblname" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Total Item
                </td>
                <td>
                    Name Item
                </td>
                <td>
                    DELETE
                </td>
            <tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody align="center">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
<?php
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var item = 1;
        $('#ADD').click(function() {
            var maxitem = parseInt($("#maxitem").val(), 10); //from max item in html
            console.log(maxitem);
            var iCount = 0;
            if ($('#product').val()) {  // check input product
                if (item <= maxitem)
                {
                    iCount = $('#tblname tbody tr').length + 1;
                    szTr = "<tr><td>";
                    szTr = szTr + iCount + "<input type='hidden' name='count[]' value='" + iCount+ "' /></td>";
                    szTr = szTr + "<td>" + $('#product').val() + " <input type='hidden' name='prd[]' value='" + $("#product").val() + "' /> </td>";
                    szTr = szTr + "<td><input type='button' class='DEL' value='DELETE'></td>";
                    szTr = szTr + "</tr>";
                    $('#tblname tbody').append(szTr);
                    item += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Max Limit !!!");
                }
            }
            else {
                alert('Enter Text');
            }
        });

        $('body').on('click', 'input.DEL', function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            item -= 1;
        });
    });
</script>
```

You are enter product name as abc, def, ghi 
then you will get the data in $_POST as follows.

```
Array
(
    [max] => 3
    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => asd
        )

    [count] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [prd] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc
            [1] => def
            [2] => ghi
        )

)
```